# Laravel sql query .. if condition in Where

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, builder

I just started to learn Laravel and converting the regular PHP code to Laravel. 
I need to execute this query in Laravel, but failed.

```
SELECT sum(qty_del) as delivery from delivery_sap a where YEAR(a.bill_date) + IF(MONTH(a.bill_date)>6, 1, 0) = 2017
```

This is what I came up with, but it failes.

```
$data = DB::table('delivery_sap')
          ->select(DB::raw('sum(qty_del) as delivery'))
          ->whereRaw('YEAR(a.bill_date) + IF(MONTH(a.bill_date)>6, 1, 0) = 2017');
```

Corrected query based on the answer below

```
$data = DB::table('delivery_sap')
      ->select(DB::raw('sum(qty_del) as delivery'))
      ->whereRaw('YEAR(bill_date) + IF(MONTH(bill_date)>6, 1, 0) = 2017')
      ->first();
```

changed from get() to first as I wanted it to return as one row

Comment: what does the log say?

Comment: Use `get()` at the end of your `whereRaw()` and see what's the result...

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I am new to laravel.. how to view the log ?

Comment: Your logs are in `/storage/logs`

Comment: I am using ajax , i got this log [2016-11-29 14:07:53] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found' in ......app\Http\Controllers\AjaxfeedController.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 {main}

Comment: Try adding a slash before DB. `\DB::table....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump the generated query by the query builder and compare it to the original query:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$query = DB::table('delivery_sap')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(qty_del) as delivery'))
    ->whereRaw('YEAR(a.bill_date) + IF(MONTH(a.bill_date)>6, 1, 0) = 2017');

dd($query->toSql());
```

It returns:

```
"select sum(qty_del) as delivery from `delivery_sap` where YEAR(a.bill_date) + IF(MONTH(a.bill_date)>6, 1, 0) = 2017"
```

Which is almost identical to your original query. You need to chain the calls with a final `get()` to retrieve the results:

```
$data = DB::table('delivery_sap AS a')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(qty_del) as delivery'))
    ->whereRaw('YEAR(a.bill_date) + IF(MONTH(a.bill_date)>6, 1, 0) = 2017')
    ->get(); // <= Here
```

Comment: I got this log --> local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found'

Comment: First, you need to import the facade or the alias into the namespace using a `use` statement. See the updated answer.

Comment: GOT IT..Thanks ! .. Point to note -- I changed the a.bill_date to bill_date as well to make it work

Comment: Yeah, right. Or you could just do this: `DB::table('delivery_sap AS a')`.

Comment: I edited the question above with the right query. I used first() instead of get() to return one row